# Magento change `updated_at` field for product by id

Tags: product, attributes, date

I need to change the `updated_at` column value for product using it's id.
I've already tried next pieces of code:

```
$productIds = [26957];
$m = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action');
$m->updateAttributes(
    $productIds,
    array('updated_at' => Varien_Date::now()),
    0 
);
```

Result:

### "Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Notice: Undefined index: value in app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 1495"

And this one:

```
$productIds = [26957];
foreach($productIds as $id) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
    $product->setUpdatedAt(Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate());
    $product->save();
}
```

Result:

### "Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 1180"

And this:

```
$_products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('id', array('in' => array(26957)));
while ($product = $_products->fetchItem()) {
    $product->setUpdatedAt(Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate());
    $product->save();
}
```

And the result is:

### Fatal error: Uncaught Mage_Core_Exception: Product ean is required in app/Mage.php on line 594

How can I do that?

Comment: Thanks for Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate() use not use Varien_Date::now()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First method - I can't help you, actually I have'n used such a model to anything.

In second piece of code, error is connected with `$productsIds` as argument of foreach loop. You can try to write the Ids in different way for example `$productIds = array(3344)`;
Although I suppose, this one should work, if you have just one product to update:

```
$id = 43453;

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$product->setUpdatedAt(Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate());
$product->save();
```

If piece `Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate()` returns correct date (can't check it now),

Third method - I am not sure if collection has method save.

Comment: Ah! I'm so stupid!)
I was trying to save my product from test script without setting admin store as current: Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);